# Explaination for Copy-Paste Excel VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code that I find on the internet but I don't want to use it while I don't know how is it function so want to ask if someone can explain it for me?

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim sh As Worksheet, Src As Range, Dst As Range
For Each sh In Application.Worksheets
    If sh.Index <> Worksheets.Count Then
        Set Src = sh.Range("A1:L34")
        Set Dst = Worksheets(3).Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Src.Rows.Count, Src.Columns.Count)
        Dst.Value = Src.Value
    End If
Next sh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that the code posted is going to copy the specific range from EACH sheet other then the LAST to the designated sheet

```
' Basically it is copying the VALUE (There are other things to copy, e.g. format, color)
' from the Source Range from all worksheet(s) to the Destination Range on another worksheet
Sub CopyPaste() 'The beginning of subroutine, you cannot return value in SubRoutine, and you can't call subroutine directly from Excel worksheet formula
Dim sh As Worksheet, Src As Range, Dst As Range 'declaring each variable
'You can look up each object in Object Explorer by F2 in VB Editor
For Each sh In Application.Worksheets 'iterate though each worksheet in all workbooks
    If sh.Index <> Worksheets.Count Then 'if this sheet isn't the last sheet
        Set Src = sh.Range("A1:L34") 'set Src variable to the src range
        Set Dst = Worksheets(3).Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Src.Rows.Count, Src.Columns.Count)
        'Worksheets(3) <-- a specific target worksheet
        '.Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) <-- trying to find the last empty cell bottom up from cell A500
        '.Resize(Src.Rows.Count, Src.Columns.Count) <-- Resizing the range so that it fits with src range
        Dst.Value = Src.Value   'Assign the value of all cells in the dst range from src range
    End If
Next sh
End Sub ' The end of subroutine
```

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing with this code is setting the value of the destination range to the value of the source range.  You are not 'copying' the cells in the normal sense of the word because you will not retain any formatting from the source cells as you would with a normal copy and paste (ie by doing Crtl+C and the Crtl+V).

This method however has it's advantages as it is significantly faster than coding a copy and paste so if it's just the values you are after it is more efficient.

Finally, you can also use a similar method to 'copy' a range to a variable which can be processed. ie, using your predefined ranges in your example:

```
Dim vVar as Variant

vVar = Src.value

for ii = lBound(vVar, 1) to uBound(vVar, 1)
    for jj = lBound(vVar, 2) to uBound(vVar, 2)
        vVar(ii, jj) = vVar(ii, jj) + 1
    next jj
next ii

Dst.Value = vVar
```

Comment: i want to know where i can find material to study loop coding  i'm confuse . it's seem pretty useful

Answer (score 1):

With this code u can **copy range A1:L34 from all sheets to the third sheet** (except the last one sheet which will not copied).

**The most important part is this one:**

```
Set Dst = Worksheets(3).Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Src.Rows.Count, Src.Columns.Count)
```

Here the **destination range** is set. For each copied sheet **the destination range is offset**, so the **copied data are not overlapped** after they are pasted.